# Get Linq Value Using Two SQL Tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am having trouble writing up the correct LINQ syntax.

I have a table called eloLists with values `ID` (int) and `Rank` (string), and a table called Users with a value `elo` (int).

I am trying to get a user's `rank` by getting their corresponding `elo`, which matches the `ID` column.

So I have a line like

`Temp = Temp + person.summonerID + "," + person.name + "," + person.summoner + "," + myQuery + ",";`

where I am try to use myQuery to get this answer. My attempt is this, but I am getting lost..

`var myQuery = db.eloLists.Select(x => x.rank.Where(x.ID = db.Users.Select(y => y.elo)));`
I am not sure if this even remotely right.

EDIT:

```
var myQuery = db.eloLists.Where(x => db.Users.Select(y => y.elo).Contains(x.ID)).Select(e => e.rank);

    foreach (var person in db.Users)
    {
        Temp = Temp + person.summonerID + "," + person.name + "," + person.summoner + "," + myQuery + ",";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method that returns a string and accept a user object.

```
public string getrank(User person) 
{
    var myQuery = db.eloLists.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == person.elo));

    if(myQuery == null) return string.Empty;

    return myQuery.Rank;
}
```

Then use:

```
foreach (var person in db.Users)
{
    Temp = Temp + person.summonerID + "," + person.name + "," + person.summoner + "," + getrank(person)  + ",";
 }
```

Comment: How do I put this into the Temp string then? Just myQuery? Or do I need to pass something?

Comment: MyQuery returns a collection of ranks.  You need to put it in a for loop and generate a comma separated string then put it in your first statement.

Comment: Ok. Your update will significantly change the answer.  I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: String.Join may be a bit cleaner rather than doing the loop